# Serilog - Possible to Change DateTime/Timestamp Format in RollingFile Sink

Tags: serilog, rollingfilesink

The Current Output of RollingFile Sink for Date time is as follows

```
2015-04-06 18:40:54.400 +10:00 [Information] Hello World!
```

Is there anyway to remove the TimeZone Offset? `+10:00`. To Achieve the following output;

```
2015-04-06 18:40:54.400 [Information] Hello World!
```

In my case, the timezone offset is superfluous fluff which is just cluttering my Text Log.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can specify the `outputTemplate` parameter to the `.RollingFile()` configuration method:

```
.WriteTo.RollingFile(
    outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff} [{Level}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}")
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. Does the trick. I wasn't aware of the formatting options in the output template

Comment: Is it possible to do it with RollingFileSink as well?

Comment: @Shetty yes, the question and answer are both discussing the rolling file sink.

Comment: RollingFile sink has been deprecated in favor of File. Property is the same: `outputTemplate`